# CSS keyframes image fadeInOut refuses to animate

Tags: html, css

I want to make two images fade smoothly between them.

Images appear on browser, but animation does not work.

I think this issue is related to @keyframes or #cf3 img.top sections... The other sections seems to work.. Tested on chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="cf">
            <img class="bottom" src="assets/1.png" />
            <img class="top" src="assets/2.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css, this is where the fading animation is at:

```
#cf {
    position: relative;
    height: 281px;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cf img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

#cf3 img.top {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: "CSS doesn't seems to work." the entire css? or just some sections?

Comment: I think this issue is related to @keyframes or #cf3 img.top sections... The other sections seems to work.

Comment: alright, can you just specify that within your post to reduce ambiguity Thank you!

Comment: Your @keyframes is above the CSS... It doesnt know it exists. Also, set an opacity in your actual img area.

Comment: I set the @keyframes above the CSS now. How do i set an opacity in my actual img area?

Comment: #cf img { opacity:1 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine you are selecting the wrong id.

Your code:

`#cf3 img.top {`

Should be

`#cf img.top {`

The keyframes can be above or below the selector both will work.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/gmyqwG)